# How to use logical or operator with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, logical-operators

How to simplify the code when using multiple or operators.
I have a list of numbers from 0 to 6 separated by logical or.Is there any way to simplify it?

```
if (filteredMnth === 'mnth') {
         
  return (new Date(exp?.date).getMonth().toString() === "0" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6"   )

}
```

Comment: It's `(a === b || a === c || a === d || ...)`. No need to simplify, because it's a pointless check and can just be deleted. `getMonth()` will always return a value between 0 and 11. You might as well just write `return true;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice pattern for this, is to create an Array of `valid` or `accepted` values and use the [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check for one from the user input:

```js
const validValues = [ 0, 1, 2 ];
const input = 2;

validValues.includes(input);
// => true

const input2 = 3;

validValues.includes(input2);
//=> false
```

As @Robby Cornelissen already mentioned in the comment, in your case it really does not make any sense, but I'm including this pattern here to answer a more generic version of your question.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case you can do ->

```js
if (filteredMnth === 'mnth') {
  return new Date(exp?.date).getMonth() <= 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having multiple values you can make use of List and includes method as below

```
const validMonths = ["1", "2", ...]
const monthToCheck = new Date(exp?.date).getMonth().toString()
if(validMonths.includes(monthToCheck)){
    //Evaluates true if value exist
}
```

Comment: Please tell me this: in what case will that check ever return false?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen validMonths.includes(monthToCheck) This evalues true....If you want false you can use not operator in front it eg. !validMonths.includes(monthToCheck) ---> evaluates true if value doesnt exist

Comment: The question has since been updated. In the original question, all the values from `0` to `11` were present, so the check would always return true, and was therefore unneeded.